# How to append a childnode in xml from string?

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing

I have a xml file like this . I am using java.

```
<ui>
        <profile name="aaa">
             <country>India</country>
        </profile>

        <profile name="xxx">
             <country>India</country>
        </profile>
</ui>
```

I want to append a childnode in node profile has attribute "aaa". I have an xml string like this

```
"<gender>Male</gender><age></age>"
```

Expected Output:

```
    <ui>
        <profile name="aaa">
             <country>India</country>
             <gender>Male</gender>
              <age></age>
        </profile>

        <profile name="xxx">
             <country>India</country>
        </profile>
</ui>
```

I used **xpath** to find the profile element with attribute "aaa"  `/ui/profile[@name='aaa']` . But , I dont know  how to append the childnodes into it.

Comment: This can be done using either Java or a XSLT template. You say "I used xpath to find the profile element with attribute 'aaa'" Can you please provide a sample of your code so we can give you the appropriate directions?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()" name="copy-all">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
            </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template
            match="ui/profile[@name = 'aaa']"
            name="add">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|*" />

                    <xsl:element name="gender">
                        <xsl:value-of select="$gender" />
                    </xsl:element>
                    <xsl:element name="age">
                        <xsl:value-of select="$age" />
                    </xsl:element>
            </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
```

`$gender` and `$age` is param values

Answer (score -1):

in java you could use [appendNode()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html#appendChild%28org.w3c.dom.Node%29) method on your extracted node

Comment: it seems some people doubt existence of this ability?